# Can I in a @RabbitConsumer find out if any messages are prefetched for this consumer

Tags: spring-amqp

I need to know if there are more messages comming for this consumer.

Right now I count the messages on the queue. But that give me only what is left on the queue and not what has been prefetched.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = QUEUENAME)
    public void recieve(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
   long messagesOnQueue = channel.messageCount(QUEUENAME);
   if(messagesOnQueue>1) {
     //add message to list
   }
   else {
      //save the list
   }
}
```

It would be really great If there was a way to tell if messages was prefetched for this consumer. Is that possible? If I can get that count then I dont care if there are messages on the queue as well.

After recieving suggestions from Gary I have changed the implementation to this, and it works.
When manually acknowledging a message it has to be done on the same channel as you get the message. But you can save a reference to it in case you need it in another thread.
In your spring boot application.yml add this

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      direct:
        prefetch: 200
      simple:
        prefetch: 200
        acknowledgeMode: MANUAL
```

Code from the consumer.

```
//The list we build and save in one transaction
    private Set<PayloadDto> unhandledPayloads = new HashSet<>();
    private long latestTag = 0L;
    private Channel latestChannel;

    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_NAME, id = "consumerId")
    public void recieve(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
        PayloadDto payloadDto = parse(message.getBody());

        unhandledPayloads.add(payloadDto);
        latestTag = message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();
        latestChannel = channel;
        if (unhandledPayloads.size() > UNHANDLED_PAYLOADS_LIMIT) {
            service.createOrUpdate(unhandledPayloads);
            queue.clear();
            channel.basicAck(latestTag, true);
        }
    }


    @EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId == 'consumerId'")
    public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            service.createOrUpdate(unhandledPayloads);
            queue.clear();
            latestChannel.basicAck(latestTag, true);
        }

    }
```

The reason we are trying to build up a list before saving it is to be able to do batch insert to make it run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but it wouldn't be hard to add a feature. Open a github issue to request it. However, I am not sure how useful it would be. If there are still messages in the queue, consuming a prefetched will fetch another.

Comment: I need it because Im building up a list of Message's. And if I either reach some limit or I come to a point where I wont get another message then I want to process that list which I have built up. (Sove them to db, batched for performance)
Right now I cant now if I am recieving the last message or if there will come another one. If the remaining messages are already prefetched, then long messagesOnQueue = channel.messageCount(QUEUENAME); will return 0. But there might be 200 more prefetched messages waiting.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this. It must be a normal thing. Needing to receive more messages before handling them.

Comment: If you are deferring processing, you need to use MANUAL ack mode to avoid losing messages after a failure. To detect no more messages, queued or prefetched, use the idle event interval and listen for container idle events, which are published when no message is received during that time. See the reference manual. When using MANUAL mode, the prefetch needs to be equal to your limit.

Comment: Hi Gary. Thx alot for answering. I have edited the question after modifying the code based on your suggestions. But. When I acknowledge the messages from the event listening method it is not working. I have googled it a bit and it seems it isnt possible. Did I misunderstand how to use the idle event?

Comment: You can't ack the delivery on a new channel; you must save a reference to the channel from the `receive()` method. Also, this assumes you have the default concurrency (1); if you have multiple threads/channels, you need a map of `channel:deliveryTag`.